# What's the difference between antiClickjack and x-frame-options

Tags: security, iframe, x-frame-options, clickjacking

What's the difference between antiClickjack script and x-frame-options?

If we set 'x-frame-options', we can't prevent clickjacking from legacy browser?

Do we need to set both antiClickjack script and x-frame-options?

Comment: _"we can't prevent clickjacking from legacy browser?"_ - what kinds of "legacy browsers" are you thinking of? [Even IE11 supports `x-frame-options`](https://caniuse.com/x-frame-options), and no-one uses IE11 anymore...

Comment: Also, you shouldn't be using `X-Frame-Options` anymore anyway: [use a Content Security Policy instead](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CSP)

Answer (score 1):

AntiClickjack script is using for very old browsers (e.g. IE 7) see availability of [x-frame-options](https://caniuse.com/x-frame-options) and [CSP:frame-ancestors](https://caniuse.com/mdn-http_headers_content-security-policy_frame-ancestors)

So it is reasonable to use x-frame-options and CSP:frame-ancestors on server side and not bothering to care about legacy browsers

more information [here](https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/Clickjacking_Defense_Cheat_Sheet.html)